# there is no project.json, global.json ... etc on .NET Core Solution with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I make a project by

```
File -> New -> Project -> Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET Core Web Application     
(.NET Core) -> Empty -> OK
```

But there is no solution and src directory and also no project.json and web.config etc.

I reference a book that uses `Visual Studio 2015`. The book's example has all files and directories I told. But I don't(I'm using VS 2017 since I can't find .NET Core for VS 2015).

How can I make those files and directories ?? 
Do I make these by manually?

Comment: There is no project.JSON anymore. But there should be a solution since you just created one

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The .NET Core was changing its internals with a slightly fast pace (although it seems it has settled down now), thus making many of the tutorials out there obsolete. [Since mid-2016](http://ivanz.com/2016/05/17/farewell-project-json-hello-msbuild-and-csproj), the project.json has been dumped in favor of "your-app-name".csproj file.

If you are following a tutorial or a book, then for anything you are supposed to write in the project.json, you must now write it in the csproj file with a slightly different format.

If I have to mess with project.json when following tutorials, I use [this official migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj/).

Comment: Oh ! I'll remember that ! and, plus in my solution, there is also no *.csproj file... I can't find... can you help me find it??

Comment: @wallah look in the actual directory via windows explorer, not from within visual studio.

Answer (score 34):

The .NET Core (and other teams) have decided to drop `project.json` and go back to **MSBuild** and `*.csproj`.

So there is no `project.json` nor `global.json` in .net core stack any more.
The alternative for `project.json` is `*.csproj` and for `global.json` is `*.sln`.

[Old csproj to new csproj: Visual Studio 2017 upgrade guide](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/)
[for more info](http://ivanz.com/2016/05/17/farewell-project-json-hello-msbuild-and-csproj)

---

**Update**: (based on Stajs comment)
[global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) is still in the stack, but neutered to only defining the SDK version.

Comment: Its a bad news :(

Comment: Correction: [`global.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) is still in the stack, but neutered to only defining the SDK version.

Comment: @Stajs, After upgrading to v15.4.4 of CLI tools you can defined SDK version in a Project property group : `<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
   <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: @Soren, the way I read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj), neither of those properties are the SDK version. I'm pretty sure everyone understands `<TargetFramework>` by now. `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` is the runtime and independent of SDK, e.g. [SDK 2.1.3 includes runtime 2.0.4](https://imgur.com/a/TAzQ3). Potentially helpful [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778064/whats-the-difference-between-targetframework-and-runtimeframeworkversion) and [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/368) discussions.