# What's the difference between <TargetFramework> and <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget, .net-core

I have the following code in a `csproj` file:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
```

In the NuGet package manager, it says that I have **Microsoft.NETCore.App version 1.0.5**

Now let's say I have the following code in the same `csproj` file:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

The NuGet package manager will now say that I have **Microsoft.NETCore.App version 1.1.4**

I'm essentially trying to use the latest framework before .NETCore 2.0 (having some EF issues when I converted) which would be .NETCore 1.1.4, but the multiple Framework attributes in `csproj` make me unsure which tag to use. I was unable to find any resources that clearly distinguishes the differences between the two.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `TargetFramework` is used by NuGet to resolve dependencies and determine the assets to be used for compiling and building the application. (Behind the scenes, a few more properties like `TargetFrameworkMoniker` and `TargetFrameworkVersion` come into play but the SDK abstracts it to a simpler `TargetFramework` for frameworks it knows about).

The `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` is specific to .NET Core / `netcoreapp`. The SDK will inject a dependency on `Microsoft.NETCore.App` for the version that `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` is set to or use the latest version it knows about for .NET Core < 2.0. The resolved version is then written to the `runtimeconfig.json` file for the .NET Core host framework resolver to resolve the version of the shared framework to load (=> .NET Core 1.1.4 runtime for example).

The reason you are able to use `1.1.*` for `netcoreapp1.0` is because the NuGet package actually contains the necessary assets to build .NET Core 1.0.* applications. However the tooling doesn't know this so you'll get a .NET Core 1.0 app but it will be loaded by the 1.1 framework because that's what ends up in the `runtimeconfig.json` file.

The important difference is:

- It only matters for self-contained executables which version of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is used.

  - This package will pull in the complete framework with the desired version when performing a self-contained publish (e.g. `dotnet publish -r win7-x64`)
  - When you run an application built for `1.0.3` but you have the `1.0.5` runtime installed, the `1.0.5` runtime will be used automatically.
  - If you don't set `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` and a new version of the SDK is released that knows about newer patch versions of .NET Core, it will use the newest version automatically. If you set the version explicitly, you may not be up-to-date without editing the project file.
- The `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` is also the minimum runtime that the application will load - if you set it to `1.0.4` and try to run on a machine that only has `1.0.3` installed, the application will not start unless you edit the `runtimeconfig.json` file.
- `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` can be set to a floating version, which is useful when targeting preview versions or daily builds, e.g. `2.1.0-preview1-*` would resolve to the newest `preview1` version available on the configured NuGet feeds.

Apart from these, there are only a few reasons to build using a higher version of `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, like a build bugfix for the `DiaSymReader` component.

In .NET Core 2.0, the version of `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` will always be `2.0.0` for "portable applications" (non-self contained) because the implementation of the framework is no longer provided by the dependencies of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and this NuGet package is only used to provide reference assemblies for compilation.

Comment: So what is the actual consequence of having both attributes as in my code sample above? The `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` tag clearly dictates with NuGet sees, taking priority over the `TargetFramework` tag. Yet if I omit the `TargetFramework` tag, the project fails to build with *The TargetFramework value '' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly.*

Comment: The target framework specifies the slice of the package that is used for compilation. So if you write `foobar1.0`, it won't work. Also, `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` is specific to the `netcoreapp` target framework

Comment: Does this mean that RuntimeFrameworkVersion in a netstandard2.0 class library has no effect at all, or in a self contained application does this still enforce a minimum runtime version for the componnet in the same way that it does for an executable?

Comment: netstandard2.0 is not coupled to a runtime, so it will have no effect on an application consuming it.

Comment: This article also provides a good explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/versions/selection. Helped me understand this particular answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, you should use runtimeframeworkversion only

If you need a specific version of the runtime when targeting .NET Core, you should use the  property in your project (for example, 1.0.4) instead of referencing the metapackage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj

Comment: `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` should only be used when a specific version of the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package is needed. There are only a limited number of use cases where you would actually want to do this.

Comment: If I comment out my TargetFramework tag, I get the following error in my `Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets` file: "The TargetFramework value '' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly"