# Upgrading from .net core 1.1 to .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am upgrading our existing platform from .Net Core 1.1 to .Net Core 2.0.
I upgraded the framework and Nuget packages associated with it.

My controllers no longer inherit from the Controller class.

However, my project is no longer building and throws cs0012 with message:
You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, publicKeyToken = cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".

This is my cs.project

```
<PropertyGroup>   
<AssemblyTitle>Demand1</AssemblyTitle>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<DebugType>portable</DebugType>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<AssemblyName>OnDemand</AssemblyName>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<PackageId>OnDemand</PackageId>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.7.10" />
<PackageReference Include="OctoPack" Version="3.6.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="StackifyMiddleware" Version="2.0.3" />
```

I followed suggestions found here:
[Solution 1](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/527) and [Another One](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/860)

- Reference Include="netstandard" as a ItemGroup
- PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App"
  Version="2.0.0"
- Removed the RuntimeFrameworkVersion
- Updated my vs community to 15.5.7

Could anyone point me to a correct direction please after spending a whole day to try resolving it.
Also I thought .net core 2 implements .net standard 2.0.0. Please do correct me if I am completely wrong here.

Comment: Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 1.0.0 .. Targerts .NET Standard 1.3, try targetting 2.0.0-dev-00023

Comment: Microsoft has an official guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/ which you do not seem to read yet.

Comment: @LexLi I forgot to mention that I have read the official documentation of migrating to .net core 2. I even tried using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package instead of all the other packages.

Comment: @DOMZE that was the only I did not update. Will try targeting it as you suggested and see

Comment: did you upgrade Visual Studio? When you update VS, .Net Core SDK will be updated accordingly (.Net Core 2.0 will be installed)

Comment: Create a 2.0 project and then cut and paste.

Comment: thank you all for the suggestions. I have upgraded seri log and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

from your `.csproj` file. This sets the target version in your `runtimeconfig.json` file to use .NET Core 1.1.1 instead of .NET Core 2.0.

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/46778275

### Other Things to Check

1. Make sure you have the [.NET Core 2.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows) installed.
2. Make sure you don't have any [`global.json` files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) in your solution that are overriding the SDK version.