# Do I still need the RuntimeFrameworkVersion project setting with .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: .net-core

With .NET Core 1.1 I had the following problem: Whenever I updated the NuGet packages in my app, my customers were forced to update their .NET Core runtime, which was annoying. I solved this by setting RuntimeFrameworkVersion to 1.1.1, so my app would run on every system with a runtime 1.1.x (x>=1) installed. So even when I upgraded my package references to 1.1.5, the app would still work on a system with only runtime 1.1.1 installed.

I understand that with .NET Core 2.1 the runtime selection behavior is a bit different (see for example this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46778275/487356) - but I don't really understand what this means for my particular scenario.

So... Does it make sense to set RuntimeFrameworkVersion to 2.1.0 for a .NET Core 2.1 app? Or is it safe to omit that? (Keep in mind I want my app to be able to run with any 2.1.x runtime installed - even if my referenced packages are newer).

Comment: If it worked on your machine but not the user's machine then you probably fibbed about the .netcore version you tested your code on.  Setting it intentionally low *might* seem like a feature, but it is not, I'd guess that the user got a very ugly exception that required your assistance.  That is a phone call nobody needs.  That it worked on 1.1.1 even though you updated to 1.1.5 is merely luck.  Just don't fib.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to set RuntimeFrameworkVersion to 2.1.0 for a .NET Core 2.1 app? Or is it safe to omit that?

This setting is most typically seen with a self-contained deployment. In this case it clearly states what version the application is using. However, it can exist for a framework-dependent deployment. In that case, it implies *minimum version* in order to run.

Assuming a framework-dependent application, if the installation site has the correct .NET Core runtimes installed then you can safely omit the RuntimeFrameworkVersion.

**References**

- *Additions to the csproj format for .NET Core*. (2019, April 8) Accessed 2020, February 11, from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#recommendations