# How to setup SDK version into .NET Core project when global.json is not enough?

Tags: .net-core

I found, from several sources, that the official way to setup SDK version into our .NET Core project is to add a global.json file into the project main folder.

By the way, let me remind some useful cli commands to run into your project folder:

`dotnet --list-sdks` list all installed SDKs

`dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.105` create the appropriate global.json file

**Now my issue:**

global.json is not applied, displayed versions does not match with my global.json

**My csproj:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\EmargementsListeners.Application\EmargementsListeners.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\EmargementsListeners.EmargProviders\Emp.Source.FakeRandomisedXbus\Emp.Source.FakeRandomisedXbus.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\EmargementsListeners.Persistence\EmargementsListeners.Persistence.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**My global.json:**

```js
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.105"
  }
}
```

**The result:**

[image: Sdk version doesn't match with global.json]

As you see, the sdk version does not match with *global.json*. It should be *NetCore.App 2.2.3*, not *2.2.0*

[image]

Placing this *global.json* into the solution folder gives the same results.

`dotnet --info` from my project:

```
dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.105
 Commit:    7cecb35b92

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.16299
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.3
  Commit:  6b8ad509b6

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.105 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

**Question:**
Which step is missing to set up the SDK version to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add

```xml
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.2.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

to your .csproj.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778064/whats-the-difference-between-targetframework-and-runtimeframeworkversion) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518059/how-to-resolve-net-core-build-error-netdsdk1061-and-warning-msb3277/52518189) for more information.

Comment: thank you but this is not the full solution, SDK keeps showing Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0. I placed this attribute on every projects of my solution...

Comment: I had the same problem. After restarting VS everything was in expected state

Answer (score 8):

If someone comes across this while not getting a .NET Core 3.0 project to open, make sure you have updated Visual Studio to the latest version. This fixed it for me when given the error below:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\Sdk not found. 
Check that a recent enough .NET Core SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.
```

Comment: Did not see at all you needed VS 2019 for .net core 3.0 and higher. Thanks!