# Azure DevOps build: "sdk\2.1.515\ [...] not found. Check that a recent enough .NET Core SDK is installed or increase the version in global.json"

Tags: wpf, .net-core, azure-devops, sdk

I get this error only in my Azure DevOps build task, and there is no explicit reference to SDK 2.1.515 anywhere in my solution (.NET Core 3.1 WPF). The "Visual Studio Version" in the build task is set to "Visual Studio 2019".

I also tried to generate a global.json with an explicit reference to the current SDK version (I found a hint here: [how to setup SDK version into .Net core project when global.json is not enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374706/how-to-setup-sdk-version-into-net-core-project-when-global-json-is-not-enough)) but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

1. On the pipeline's "Taks" tab, select "Pipeline, Build pipeline" (the light blue panel below the tab) and set the "Agent Specification" to "windows-2019".

[image]

2. Make sure the "Visual Studio Version" (in the build solution task) is set to "latest" or to "Visual Studio 2019".

[image]

Comment: Great ! You could accept your answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues , thanks.