# How do I target a specific .NET core version

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

On my dev machine I have .NET core 5.0.5, 5.0.6 and 5.07 hosting bundles installed.
On my prod machine I have .NET core 5.0.5

In my .csproj file I have:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>5.0.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I build using VS2019.

After deploying to prodution I get the following in the event viewer:

```
Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.7' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.15 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

Obviously I do not want to use 5.0.7
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` or making the application self-contained.

Comment: Removing RuntimeFrameworkVersion  will use the latest version installed when building. So same result.

My build is creating an EXE file of my project and my web.config is configured to run it. But no luck

Comment: Have not tried with .NET 5 but you should be able to use [`global.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x) to specify the SDK version to build the app.

Comment: It will build with the latest installed, but what it runs with is decided by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward

Comment: @fredrik At first I didn't have that node and it caused the same problem which is why I added it.

I think .NET 5 is broken :(

Comment: @GuruStron Tried global.json
didn't do anything..

Comment: Then make the app self-contained and it won't matter what's installed on the machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was confirmed in .NET5 and said to be fixed in .NET6
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33941

Answer (score -1):

Publishing your app as **self-contained** produces a platform-specific executable.

- **[Publish self-contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained)**

In this way, you can **control the version** of .NET deployed with your application.

- You can **[click on the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778064/whats-the-difference-between-targetframework-and-runtimeframeworkversion?answertab=votes#tab-top)** below to see a more detailed explanation.

Comment: 1. I can't control the version in .NET 5. That's the point. I've already tried all these tags.
2. self-contained is not what I prefer.
3. Already opened a github issue with the devs.

Comment: @AlonSchachter, so you can't change the targeted framework in Project > [the name of your application] Properties > Application?

Comment: Not to a specific build of .NET 5